# How to avoid race condition and keep reference when working with global temp tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, race-condition, reference-counting, global-temp-tables

I have the following logic in one of my SPs:

```
if object_id('tempdb..##val','u') is null begin
    create table ##val (
                name varchar(512)
                ,val nvarchar(max)
    )
end

    insert ##val (name,val)values('some unique name','abcdef')
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887989/global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server) has answer that indicates checking `if object_id(`, but I have these concerns:

1) is this check thread-safe from race condition point of view ? Specifically, do I need to use `sp_GetAppLock`/`sp_ReleaseAppLock` ?

2) Does if condition reserve reference on table `##val` ? Specifically, is it possible that all other sessions release reference on `##val` right after negative result of `if` condition making  `insert` statement fail due to not existing ##val table ? And if yes how to reserve and keep reference on `##val` from current session without locking rows in that table.

Comment: Do you want multiple sessions to use the same copy of the ##global temp table? Since this effectively reduces concurrency to one (unless you want them to share data), this is why you rarely see global temp tables as a permanent solution. Are you sure you mean to use a global temp table? Why not just have a permanent table that always exists, then you don't have to check for existence etc.?

Comment: Yes, I want multiple sessions use the same copy of ##global temp table. I agree than permanent table is better solution, but I may be disallowed to create tables in specific database on the fly and also process of creating and modifying perm tables is quite complicated at my work place. Also sometimes I want to have global database independent meta-data to deal with multiple databases for migration/renaming scripts.