# How to creating a global temp table in one stored procedure, and use it in another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables, global-temp-tables

I have a dynamic stored procedure that returns a result set.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [test].[proc] 
    (@id INT,
     @temp_table_name VARCHAR(50) = '') 
AS
BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM test.table con';

    IF (LEFT(@temp_table_name, 2) = '##')
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @move_to_temp_sql varchar(max);

        SET @move_to_temp_sql = REPLACE(@sql, 'FROM test.table con', 'INTO ' + @temp_table_name + ' FROM test.table con');
    END

    EXECUTE(@sql)
END
```

I'm passing the name of the temporary table when I'm calling the stored procedure from another stored procedure.

```
[test].[proc] 1, '##test'
```

I would like to access the global temp table `##test` from the calling stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ##test;
```

I get

> Invalid object name '##test'

when I try this.

Please note: the structure of the table would vary so I cannot define the temp table in my calling stored procedure, it has to be done in the dynamic stored procedure.

Comment: What's stopping you? Do you get an error? I personally would create a regular temp table outside and populate it inside

Comment: @siggemannen I get invalid object name when I try to access the temp table.

Comment: It's cause it goes out of scope probably. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887989/global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server you need to rethink your solution. You can just pass a real table name and drop it when you're done

Comment: Thats because the temp table does not exist when you try to create the SP.  I would suggest creating a permeant staging table instead that you just truncate each time before processing.

Comment: 2 problems with creating a permanent/temp table at the calling procedure
1) I donot know the structure of the table before hand, i will keep varying
2) There is an issue of 2 calls updating the same table at the same time

Comment: Create a variable called @tablename = 'sometable_' + replace(cast(newid() as sysname), '-', '_')  pass it instead of ##table. This way it will work and you get a pretty unique table name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stored procedure never created the temp table you are intended to create, rather it's just selecting the records from `test.table`. That's why you are failing to find the temp table.

instead of `EXECUTE(@sql)` you need to use `EXECUTE(@move_to_temp_sql)`.

Also you need to declare variable `@sql` in your stored procedure. Please try this. You will get your desired temp table.

You can also simply

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [proc] 
    (@id INT,
     @temp_table_name VARCHAR(50) = '') 
AS
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max);        

    IF (LEFT(@temp_table_name, 2) = '##')
    BEGIN

        SET @sql = 'select * INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@temp_table_name) + ' FROM test.table con';
    END

    EXECUTE(@sql)
END
```

Comment: The logic of declaring and setting `@sql` inside an `IF`, then executing it afterwards escapes me. Tip: The best practice when assembling object names into dynamic SQL statements is to use [`QuoteName()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) to avoid problems with odd names, e.g. `New Table` with a space or reserved words like `From`.

Comment: @HABO thank you so much for the observation and advice. Best wishes.